# Help identifying Components

Tags: varistor

I need help tracking down 2 replacement parts.
From what I know they are 1 Varistor and 1 Pico Fuse.
Could anyone confirm that and tell me what I should be looking for to replace them. Googling the writing on them doesn't really get me anywhere so can someone break down what the numbers mean and or where to order replacements.
Thanks very much
Nelson

This is the info I get off them
ZOV 07d471k cq01p (Varistor?)
STB3.15A (Pico Fuse?)

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

1. STB1315A Time-Lag Pico Fuse 250V, 3.15 A [link](http://www.rtsensor.com/?/goods/id-157/)
2. 07D471k Varistor [link](http://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Bourns/MOV-07D471K/?qs=lgttKnAd%252b2A9pbKqMUoJ0A%3D%3D)

Comment: Ok that's great! I came across those links before but wasn't sure they were correct. My only thing is does it matter that the Varistor is a ZOV (Zinc Oxide Varistor) and the ones found for sale are MOV (Metal Oxide Varistor ) Thanks Again!

Comment: @NelsonNico I do believe that zinc is a metal. Most MOVs are made out of zinc oxide, with some other materials mixed in. Basically it is important that it matches the specs of the original.

Comment: I'm having a hard time tracking down somewhere to order from. I'm in canada so I'm ok with any US site but everywhere seems to be from China. Anyone have recommendations where to order components that won't take 2 months to get?

Comment: @Nelson Mouser, Digikey, Farnell, ... You need to improve your Google skills.